# Combinatorial Proofs with Summation on One Side

Tags: combinatorics, summation, proof-writing, combinatorial-proofs

How do I go about approaching the following problem?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 C(n,k) = n(n+1)2^{n-2}$$

I don't know how to interpret the summation of something combinatorially, especially with a k^2 term. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Products correspond to making independent choices. So, for $k^2 C(n, k)$, you want to come up with a process which involves choosing one of $C(n, k)$ elements, then choosing between $k$ elements, then choosing between another $k$ elements. For instance, what if you chose a committee and then chose a president and vice president. What sum would that result in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combinatorial proof:
Given $n$ people, choose a committee of size $k$, then choose a chairperson and a vice chair person (possibly the same person) ... This the LHS.

Another way ... if the the chair & vice are the same person $n2^{n-1}$ ... & if the are different $n(n-1) 2^{n-2}$ ... add these, this is the RHS.

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thank you so much!!